# Why doesn't this rearrangement work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We know that $e^{2 \pi i} = 1$. Dividing both sides of this by $e^{2 \pi}$ gives us $e^{i}=e^{-2\pi}$. However, this is not true. Why hasn't this rearrangement worked?

Comment: There is a mistake: $e^{2\pi i}/e^{2\pi}=e^{e^{2\pi(i-1)}}$ and not $e^{-2\pi}$.

Comment: Thanks, butt why? Surely $e^{2 \pi i} = e^{2 \pi} e^{i}$?

Comment: No, $e^{2\pi}e^{i} =e^{2\pi+i}$ and $e^{2\pi i}=(e^{2\pi})^{i}$.

Comment: Sorry, of course it is! Sorry for asking such a dense question.

Comment: One more (probably stupid question): since $(e^{i})^{2 \pi} = 1$, how come $e^{i} \neq 1$?

Comment: Well we also have $(-1)^2 = 1$ and $i^4 = 1$ but of course $-1\neq 1$ and $i\neq 1$. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: $e^{i}=\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$ which is a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $e^{2\pi i}$
  $$e^{2\pi i}=e^{\left(2\pi k+2\pi\right)i}=1\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
- $\arg(e^{2\pi i})$
  $$\arg(e^{2\pi i})=\arg(e^{0i})=0$$

So:

$$\frac{e^{2\pi i}}{e^{2\pi}}=\frac{1}{e^{2\pi}}=e^{2\pi i-2\pi}=e^{0i-2\pi}=e^{0-2\pi}=e^{-2\pi}$$